# Xamarin Forms: Always reading the initial notification data in foreground mode, do I need to add any unsubscribe for intent after read it once?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below is my Notification Payload:

```
{
    "to" : "device-fcm-token",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "Hiii",
        "title": "Title"
    },
    "data" : {
        "commentMessageType": "customer",
        "revealedLocationName": "Moncy Events Center",
        "revealedLocationId": "77451",
        "requestData":
            {
                "request": {
                    "itemId": 3226,
                    "itemTitle": "Need car maintanance service",
                    "itemDescription": "Need car maintanance service",
                    "itemType": "request",
                    "itemStatus": 1,
                    "itemSource": 0,
                    "itemPriority": 1
                },
                "category": "Vehicle Rental",
                "companyId": 0,
                "companyName": null
            }
        }  
}
```

I need to read this commentMessageType, revealedLocationName, revealedLocationId and requestData in all modes.

Below is my `SendNotificatios` function:

```
public void SendNotificatios(string body, string Header)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Mutable);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .SetContentTitle(Header)
                        .SetContentText(body)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_notification)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
        else
        {
            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Utils.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetContentTitle(Header)
                        .SetContentText(body)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_notification)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Utils.CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

Using `Intent` I am able to read the `requestData` value in background or killed mode like below.

```
if (Intent.Extras != null)
{
    foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
    {
        var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
        if (key == "requestData") 
        {
            if (value?.Length > 0)
            {
                //here value is the requestData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similar way how can I read the commentMessageType, revealedLocationName, revealedLocationId in background or killed mode? Also suggest a solution to read the data when the app is open(foreground mode)?

**Update**

I am [referring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows) this blog and now I have fixed most of the issues, only a minor issue is pending.

I have fixed reading data on background mode like below:

```
if (Intent.Extras != null)
{
    foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
    {
        var requestData = Intent.Extras.GetString("requestData");
        var commentMessageType = Intent.Extras.GetString("commentMessageType");
        var revealedLocationName = Intent.Extras.GetString("revealedLocationName");
        var revealedLocationId = Intent.Extras.GetString("revealedLocationId");
        if (key == "requestData")
        {
            if (requestData?.Length > 0)
            {
                isNotification = true;
                LoadApplication(new App(contactsService, null, requestData, commentMessageType,
            revealedLocationName, revealedLocationId));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For foreground I have added `intent.PutExtra` on `SendNotificatios`, below is my updated code:

```
public void SendNotificatios(string body, string Header, IDictionary<string, string> data)
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    //below section added
    foreach (var key in data.Keys)
    {
        intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
    }
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Mutable);

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .SetContentTitle(Header)
                    .SetContentText(body)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_notification)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
    else
    {
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Utils.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .SetContentTitle(Header)
                    .SetContentText(body)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_notification)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    
        var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Utils.CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

Now my problem is in foreground mode, always showing the initial notification data. When a new notification received in foreground mode, at that time also the initial notification data is reading. Is there any unsubscribe or remove data from intent after it read once?

**Update - 14/07/2023**

I made a few updates by referring [Handle incoming notifications on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications#handle-incoming-notifications-on-android).

I have added the `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop` on the `Activity` section.

Also override the `OnNewIntent` and added `CreateNotificationFromIntent` on it.

**Updated code:**

```
[Activity(
        // ...
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop]
        
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // ...
    LoadApplication(new App());
    //background or kiled mode
    CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent);
}

//foreground mode
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    CreateNotificationFromIntent(intent);
}

void CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.Extras != null)
    {
        foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
        {
            var requestData = intent.Extras.GetString("requestData");
            var commentMessageType = intent.Extras.GetString("commentMessageType");
            var revealedLocationName = intent.Extras.GetString("revealedLocationName");
            var revealedLocationId = intent.Extras.GetString("revealedLocationId");
            if (key == "requestData")
            {
                if (requestData?.Length > 0)
                {
                    isNotification = true;
                    LoadApplication(new App(requestData, commentMessageType, revealedLocationName, revealedLocationId));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After all these also I am facing the same issue in foreground mode. The first notification in foreground mode is always showing for all the notifications receiving in foreground mode. But If I make the app in background mode and send a notification and tap on it it is working fine.

**Update**

Here is my [demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ffxAQqmcq1yNp3nZF4MdA8WIUMtDqAg/view?usp=sharing) and [postman collection](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mdeusXY79wJpJ2pETMUuG04gfN6aWRXB/view?usp=sharing) to recreate this issue.

**How to recreate this issue:**

- Run the demo project into an android device and fetch your device FCM token. Add it on the postman collection APIs, on `your device token` part.
- Then send API named Notification 1 in foreground mode. When tap on it then notification1 text will show on the UI.
- Then if you send Notification 2 in foreground mode and tap on it again notification1 text will show on the UI instead of notification2.
- **The initial notification data is showing for all the notifications received in foreground mode.** But no such issue in background mode and everything is working fine on background mode.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have updated the question with more details, could you please have a look?

Comment: `When a new notification received in foreground mode, at that time also the initial notification data is reading.`  Is the data of the new notification updated, or is it the same as the previous notification?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT The new notification data is entirely different from the initial one

Comment: What's the version of the nugets you used? You can try to update them to the latest version.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Which nuget package I need to update?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgX3i.png

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have updated all the android nuget packages, still same output. In foreground mode whatever the notification received initially, that notification data is not replacing for other notification, always reading the initial notification data.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I made a few updates with new findings, could you please have a look?

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Question updated with demo link and steps to recreate this issue. Could you please check?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Did you get a chance to check this issue? I am stuck on this for a month, please help.